# Sending different signals for system shutdown and manual stops in supervisord

Tags: daemon, supervisord, autoscaling

I have a set of auto-scaled EC2 instances that run a daemon managed by supervisord on each instance.

I want to differentiate the clean-up behavior for the following cases:

- when shutting down instances (e.g., scaling-in)
  i.e., shutting down supervisord itself
  -> do an extra clean-up process
- when I manually stop the daemon for maintenance (e.g., upgrades)
  i.e., keeping supervisord alive but only shutting down my daemon
  -> do a fast clean-up process

Currently supervisord has only `stopsignal` configuration which sends the same signal in both cases. [It seems that](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/147) the authors decided *not* to support extra reload/restart signals for graceful shutdown.
(In my case, I want to distinguish two *shutdown* signals depending on the shutdown reason, not wanting to have reload/restart signals, though.)

How could I make my daemons to distinguish those two cases (with supervisord or maybe without supervisord)?